# Constructing natural numbers from nothing

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics, set-theory

I found that many of us (mathematicians) try to construct natural numbers defined from the intuitive concept 'size of the set'. They take *ϕ*, the empty set, as the starting point, then define and represent the size of the set *A*<sub>1</sub> =  {*ϕ*} as 1, now define 2 as the size of the set *A*<sub>2</sub> = {*ϕ*, *A*<sub>1</sub>} and so on.

My doubt: Can we take an absolute empty set *ϕ* without relating to a well defined universal set *U*?

Comment: I think there are set theories where the empty set axiom is inferred, but I'm not sure. Paul Corazza has worked out a fairly detailed theory of elementary embeddings that appears to trace the natural numbers back to a sequence involving *j* = an embedding term, iterated over itself (I think on this level he uses a weak Dedekind embedding, not a full-on *V*-into-*M* structure). More broadly, one might represent the empty set as given as the complement of *U* first, though defining complementation without negation/zero will be tricky.

Comment: Also, don't take me as being overly finicky, but the construction of the natural numbers is usually carried out in ordinal terms, and the A, {A}, {A, {A}} ... kind of sequence that unfolds is an ordinal sequence (in fact distilled right out of iterated Kuratowski pairing vs. the union/succession notation). Granted, infinite cardinals "share" multiple ordinals, whereas finite cardinals go hand-in-hand with their ordinals, but note that cardinality questions, when posed independently of ordinal ones, allow for primitive disorderly cardinals (e.g. self-singletons).

Comment: Yes, we can. In ZF the empty set is introduced through an [axiom of its own](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_empty_set), not through the [axiom of specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#3._Axiom_schema_of_specification_(also_called_the_axiom_schema_of_separation_or_of_restricted_comprehension)) that you are thinking of, which does require some ambient "universal set".

Comment: Note that 2 is defined as the set {0,1}. It's not defined as the "size" of that set. 2 is literally the set {0,1} in ZF. If your question is where does the empty set come from, sometimes there's a specific axiom saying the empty set exists. Other comments have deeper answers.

Comment: The "standard" set-theoretical construction of numbers does not "create" natural numbers: it builds a structure made of sets that behave like (i.e. has the same properties of) the natural numbers structure.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, on the other hand, Frege had a plausible argument about natural numbers actually being sets, but different sets. Basically, n is the set of all sets with cardinality n. He had a way to define cardinality without reference to numbers.

Comment: @DavidGudeman - no sets at all. Frege was a "Logicist" and defined number starting from [concepts](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege/#NatNum).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA He may have started from concepts, but he then defined a set as the extension of a concept and defined numbers as sets so they would be extensional.